# Compactly supported harmonic forms

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, hodge-theory

If $(\mathcal{M},g)$ is a compact Riemannian manifold (without boundary), then it is well-known that a $k$-form $\alpha$ is harmonic, i.e. $\Delta\alpha=0$, where $\Delta$ is the Laplace-Beltrami operator if and only if $\mathrm{d}\alpha=0$ and $\delta\alpha=0$.

Now, if $\mathcal{M}$ is non-compact (without boundary), then this is in general not true. However, is it true if $\alpha$ is compactly supported? In the compact case, the statement is proven using the Hodge decomposition, however, in the non-compact, I was not able to find a similar result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\Delta = d\delta + \delta d$ and $\delta$ is the formal adjoint to $d$. The direction $d\alpha = \delta \alpha =0\Rightarrow \Delta \alpha$ is obvious and $\alpha$ does not have to be of compact support. For the other direction, if $\Delta \alpha = 0$, then

\begin{align}
 0=\int_M \langle \Delta \alpha, \alpha\rangle d\mu_M &= \int \langle d\delta \alpha + \delta d\alpha, \alpha\rangle d\mu_M \\
&= \int_M (\| d\alpha\|^2 + \|\delta \alpha\|^2) d\mu_M. 
\end{align}

This implies $d\alpha = \delta\alpha = 0$. In the proof we used that $\alpha$ is of compact support, so that the integration is well-defined.

Comment: Also since $\alpha$ is compactly supported there are no boundary terms in the integration by parts.

Answer (score 5):

It's true, as @ArcticChar proved, that if $\alpha$ is harmonic and compactly supported then $d\alpha = \delta\alpha = 0$.

But this is not very useful on a noncompact manifold, because if $\alpha$ is harmonic and compactly supported on a noncompact manifold, then it vanishes on a nonempty open set, so it's identically zero by unique continuation.

A more useful result is that if $M$ is complete and noncompact and $\alpha$ is a harmonic form in the Sobolev space $H^1(M)$ ($L^2$ forms whose weak first derivatives are in $L^2$), then $d\alpha = \delta \alpha = 0$. The same proof applies, using the fact that smooth compactly supported forms are dense in $H^1(M)$ [see Aubin, *Some Nonlinear Problems in Riemannian Geometry*, Theorem 2.6].

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Just a short question: The claim that $\alpha\in\Omega_{c}^{k}(\mathcal{M})$ harmonic implies $\alpha=0$ is true for general $k$? I just knew it for the case $k=0$.

Comment: May I also ask a short follow up question: If $\alpha$ is a compactly-supported $k$-form on a non-compact manifold, does it admit a decomposition of the form $\alpha=h+\mathrm{d}\beta+\delta\gamma$ for $h$ harmonic?

Comment: @B.Hueber: There are unique continuation results for general elliptic systems, which apply to the Hodge Laplacian in all degrees. Here's one such result: https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/jiip-2020-0073/html?lang=en

Comment: As to your second question, I think the answer is probably no in general. But there are such results for certain manifolds. For example, this paper proves it for Euclidean and hyperbolic spaces:  https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.11764

Comment: Dear Prof. @JackLee: Do you know any other reference for proof other than Aubin's book? I wonder why contents of most of Aubin' books are almost never mentioned in other books. (I ask this because of [this  Ryan Budney's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/426263#comment1095826_426263) ..)

Comment: @C.F.G: It'a also in Hebey's "Sobolev Spaces on Riemannian Manifolds," Theorem 2.7.

Comment: Dear Prof. @JackLee Thank you very much for your reply. Regarding the second comment. I agree that for general $L^{2}$ (or $H^{1}$) such a decomposition might not be true for every manifolds, however, in my case I am considering a compactly-supported form, which is a much stronger assumption than just $L^{2}$. So, I was wondering if I can write $\alpha=h+\mathrm{d}\beta+\delta\gamma$ for some compactly-supported form $\alpha$. By your answer, one might also argue that $h=0$ to get an even simpler decomposition.

Comment: This is getting pretty far from your original question. Why don't you pose a new question explaining exactly what you're looking for?